Streaming a wav audio file in memory using HTML <audio> tag
I am writing a Streamlit app that includes a simple chat-bot type interface. I want the chatbot to have text to speech capability, so I am using OpenAI TTS to generate a .wav file chunk by chunk. The only way I see to play this audio automatically is using st.html() to write custom HTML code to autoplay audio. However, I am completely inexperienced in HTML and javascript.
This discussion post uses the HTML  tag to play an audio file in memory by first encoding it into base64. However, I can't use it in my case since I can't byte64 encode my entire audio file before playback. I really can't find any other way to streaming a constantly growing audio buffer in HTML. Some articles suggest using web audio API but I don't completely understand them and am wondering if there is an easier approach.
How can I play a chunk encoded .wav audio buffer through HTML?
